# 3D STL Vector in VC++ 2015 vs VC++2008

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I migrate project C++ in VS 2008 to 2015, and it have some problem in 3D STL vector like this:

```
int a; 
int b; 
vector<vector<vector<int> > > vec(a,b) ///this line in VC2008 run OK but error occur in VC2015 say error (No initialization constructor found)
```

my solution for this is:

```
int a;
int b;
vector<vector<int> > vecb(b);
vector<vector<vector<int> > > vec(a,vecb);
```

Is my solution right?

Comment: Your solution is the same as `vector<vector<vector<int> > > vec(a);`

Comment: I change vector<vector<int> > vecb to vector<vector<int> > vecb(b). After the change, Is new "vec" same as in VC2008?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your code worked in Visual Studio 2008. What was it supposed to do?

Comment: No idea if the second sample is equivalent to what the first gives you in VS2008.   Because the first sample of code is invalid C++.   If VS2008 accepts it then the compiler is permitting `b` to be implicitly converted to a `vector<vector<int> >` (which has not been valid C++ in any standard).    Try describing what you intend the construct to give you in absolute terms, rather than in reference to a broken compiler.

Comment: I am a OUTSOURCER, my customer want me to migrate there project to new version of visual studio, so i try to do same like they do in there project. And if i want to test this code work or not i need make large amount of effort to test this, therefore i want to sure it is same.